# Unable linking a ".o" object file

Tags: c++, linux, linker, linker-errors

I have a question about my current C++ Linux project.
I'm building a source code and linking it (IDE is QtCreator) to a .o (not .lib) file, provided by a supplier.
When building the source files, it seems everythig is fine, but when I reach the link time, the command line output indicates lot of undefined reference errors.
Here is the used cli and its output:

```
arm-nobuos-linux-gnueabi-g++  -march=armv7-a -mfloat-abi=hard -mfpu=neon -mtune=cortex-a9 --sysroot=/opt/nobu-x11/4.1.15-1.1.1/sysroots/cortexa9hf-vfp-neon-nobuos-linux-gnueabi -c -pipe  -O2 -pipe -g -feliminate-unused-debug-types -g -DLINUX=1 -Wall -W -D_REENTRANT -fPIC -DQT_QML_DEBUG -DQT_CORE_LIB -I../qt_selexes_test2 -I. -isystem /opt/nobu-x11/4.1.15-1.1.1/sysroots/cortexa9hf-vfp-neon-nobuos-linux-gnueabi/usr/include -isystem /opt/nobu-x11/4.1.15-1.1.1/sysroots/cortexa9hf-vfp-neon-nobuos-linux-gnueabi/usr/include/qt5 -isystem /opt/nobu-x11/4.1.15-1.1.1/sysroots/cortexa9hf-vfp-neon-nobuos-linux-gnueabi/usr/include/qt5/QtCore -I. -I/opt/nobu-x11/4.1.15-1.1.1/sysroots/cortexa9hf-vfp-neon-nobuos-linux-gnueabi/usr/lib/qt5/mkspecs/linux-oe-g++ -o moc_mrs_flasher.o moc_mrs_flasher.cpp
arm-nobuos-linux-gnueabi-g++  -march=armv7-a -mfloat-abi=hard -mfpu=neon -mtune=cortex-a9 --sysroot=/opt/nobu-x11/4.1.15-1.1.1/sysroots/cortexa9hf-vfp-neon-nobuos-linux-gnueabi -Wl,-O1 -Wl,--hash-style=gnu -Wl,--as-needed -o qt_selexes_test2 main.o dcan.o moc_dcan.o moc_mrs_flasher.o   /SviluppoCodice/parodi/SW/updateAnalogCan_Wurth/qt_selexes_test2_20170511/qt_selexes_test2/mrs_flasher.o -lQt5Core -lpthread 
main.o: In function `main':
main.cpp:26: undefined reference to `mrs_flasher::scan_module_wait(long, int, int, unsigned char&, std::__cxx11::basic_string<char, std::char_traits<char>, std::allocator<char> >&)'
main.cpp:37: undefined reference to `mrs_flasher::select_module(int, std::__cxx11::basic_string<char, std::char_traits<char>, std::allocator<char> >&)'
main.cpp:41: undefined reference to `mrs_flasher::download_s19_wait(std::__cxx11::basic_string<char, std::char_traits<char>, std::allocator<char> >, std::__cxx11::basic_string<char, std::char_traits<char>, std::allocator<char> >&)'
```

Looking at the .o file it seems that:

- the target machine of the compiler is the same (by invoking the command file on the .o files generated by compiling my cpp files and the one provided by the supplier, both of them generate the following output  "**ELF 32-bit LSB relocatable, ARM, EABI5 version 1 (SYSV), not stripped**"
- the .o file contains the undefined referenced objects (I used the command **strings mrs_flasher.o | grep scan_module_wait** in order to search for the
  *"undefined reference to `mrs_flasher::scan_module_wait"* The command output is:

> scan_module_wait
>
> _ZN11mrs_flasher16scan_module_waitEliiRhRSs
>
> _ZN11mrs_flasher16scan_module_waitEliiRhRSs
> )

Is there someone that can help me further investigate this issue? Is there something that can I post in order to help facing the problem?
Thank you  Giovanni

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The explanation is that the object file your supplier has provided -
which I guess is `/SviluppoCodice/parodi/SW/updateAnalogCan_Wurth/qt_selexes_test2_20170511/qt_selexes_test2/mrs_flasher.o` -
was not compiled with the same compiler you are using or with an ABI compatible compiler.

You can see this from the fact that your compiler is emitting a call to:

```
mrs_flasher::scan_module_wait(long, int, int, unsigned char&, std::__cxx11::basic_string<char, std::char_traits<char>, std::allocator<char> >&)
```

whereas your object file defines mangled symbol:

```
_ZN11mrs_flasher16scan_module_waitEliiRhRSs
```

which demangles as:

```
$ c++filt _ZN11mrs_flasher16scan_module_waitEliiRhRSs
mrs_flasher::scan_module_wait(long, int, int, unsigned char&, std::basic_string<char, std::char_traits<char>, std::allocator<char> >&)
```

Notice that the function your compiler requests has as fourth parameter of type:

```
std::__cxx11::basic_string<char, std::char_traits<char>, std::allocator<char> >&
```

whereas the one defined by the object file has a fourth parameter of the different type:

```
std::basic_string<char, std::char_traits<char>, std::allocator<char> >&
```

So the function signatures do not match and the linker finds no definition for the function your
compiler calls.

The difference between the two function signatures:

```
std::__cxx11::basic_string
```

versus:

```
std::basic_string
```

tells us that your compiler compiles to the [C++11 ABI](https://gcc.gnu.org/onlinedocs/libstdc++/manual/using_dual_abi.html),
introduced with GCC 5.1, but the compiler that built your object file does not.

The likeliest cause is that your provider built the object file with GCC < 5.1. You cannot link this object
file with ones built with your compiler - unless you want to build your own code to the antiquated ABI, which I assume you don't. You should get your provider to provide a new one that conforms to
the C++11 ABI.

Comment: Thank you Mike, I will give a try to the old ABI approach (in order to validate the provider library). 
Then I will ask him to rebuild the .o using my compiler.
Now I have to understand how to use old ABI in QTCreator